# How to use a callback function in python?

Tags: python, authentication, python-2.7, callback, functional-programming

I wonder how to correctly use python 2.7 callback functions.

I have some callback functions from Cherrypy auth examples in my code.

(These callbacks return a function that can evaluate to True or False, depending on the logged in user being in a group or not.)

I wonder if a callback is executed or not if I write a piece of code like this:

Given the definition from the library is:

```
def member_of(groupname):
    def check():
        if groupname == 'admin':
          if cherrypy.request.login == 'joe':
            return True
          if cherrypy.request.login == 'toni':
            return True
          return False
        return False
        # .... (other groups checked in the same way)
    return check # returns a callback function from my understanding?
```

How can I apply and execute the callback in my code?

If I put it like this:

```
 if member_of('admin'):
    do_something()
  else:
    do_something_else()
```

Will this execute the calllback and check for the admin group? Or will it find out if the value of "member_of" is a function definition and a function definition is probably always a "True" value (or maybe a False value) but both are wrong, because it needs to be executed

Can you enlighten me on this? How can I make sure a callback is executed? An how can I pass it around as it is?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In python, like in many other languages, a variable can also contain a function and you can pass them around like other variables that contain e.g. numbers or strings.

CherryPy's `member_of` function itself does return a function in your example.

I am explaining it in simple steps:

If you write `member_of()` it returns the result of the function member_of() which is the function with the name `check` in this case.

```
cb_function = member_of('admin')
```

At this point the variable `cb_function` holds the result of calling the function `member_of`, and in the last line `member_of` returns `check`, which was defined within the function `member_of` as another function!

You have to call the first result again, because you can and you have to treat it in almost the same way as a local function, that you defined in the current context, to get the final result, by doing something like:

```
my_result =  cb_function()
```

And then you would continue and use the result. For example you could check its boolean value:

```
if my_result:
  # do something
  ...
```

The 3 steps from above together can be written shorter:

```
cb_function = member_of('admin')
  if cb_function():
    # do something
    ...
```

Or even shorter:

```
if member_of('admin')():
  # do something
  ...
```

At first it may appear a little strange in python to have the double `()()`, but if you think about it for a while it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

If you execute it, it is plain simple.

`member_of()` will return method object check.
you have to execute to get result by doing something like if `member_of('admin')()`:
or,

```
k=member_of('admin')
if k():
```

To do your task.