# Inner function in Python

Tags: python-2.7

```
def getMessage1(self, id, queueName):

    uuid = id

    def onMessage(ch, method, properties, body):
        if uuid in body:
            requeued_messages = self.channel.stop_consuming()

            return body

    self.channel.basic_consume(consumer_callback = onMessage, queue = queueName, no_ack = True)
    self.channel.start_consuming()
    return onMessage(ch, method, properties, body)
    #global name 'ch' is not defined
```

I am trying to define two function as shown in the code. I am try to return `body` to the inner function and I also want to the same `body` to return to my outer function i.e `getMessage1`.

But this above code returns me with

> "function onMessage at 0x0000000006642128" not the "body"

and also I want my inner function to get the come out of the loop only when the `uuid` is present in the `body`.

Returned `body` is a string

here is the basic_consume function that I am using

```
def basic_consume(self, consumer_callback,
                  queue='',
                  no_ack=False,
                  exclusive=False,
                  consumer_tag=None,
                  arguments=None):
    """Sends the AMQP command Basic.Consume to the broker and binds messages
    for the consumer_tag to the consumer callback. If you do not pass in
    a consumer_tag, one will be automatically generated for you. Returns
    the consumer tag.

    For more information on basic_consume, see:
    http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.consume

    :param method consumer_callback: The method to callback when consuming
        with the signature consumer_callback(channel, method, properties,
                                             body), where
                            channel: pika.Channel
                            method: pika.spec.Basic.Deliver
                            properties: pika.spec.BasicProperties
                            body: str, unicode, or bytes
```

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
THe code your posted is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

In order for `getMessage1` to return the body from `onMessage`, you need to return the call of `onMessage`.  As it stands now, you're returning a function.

Consider these two examples:

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        return "This is from Bar"
    return bar()

print foo()
```

Result:
`This is from Bar`

vs

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        return "This is from Bar"
    return bar

print foo()
```

Result:
`<function bar at 0x0270E070>`

Answer (score 0):

1. You get the message `function onMessage at 0x0000000006642128` because your return statement `return onMessage` returns the function onMessage without evaluating the results.  If you want to evaluate the function you need something like `return onMessage(channel, method, properties, body)` with the values/variables you want evaluated inside the parentheses.  Below is a working example of an inner and outer function:

   ```
   def sumOfSquares(a,b):
       def square(c):
           return (c*c)
       return square(a)+square(b)
   print(sumOfSquares(2,3))
   ```
2. I don't see a loop in either function.  Please provide more information on the second part of your question.

Comment: I have sent the complete code, in the answer part please

Comment: SK, I am lost.  Your onMessage function takes 4 arguments (channel, method, properties, and body).  The function only uses body.  You can probably delete the other 3.  I don't think you even need the function -- put the logic in the loop.

Comment: if you look at the code    
self.channel.basic_consume(consumer_callback = onMessage, queue = queueName, no_ack = True)

over here i am using consumer_callback function that accepts 4 argument so I defined a function with 4 argument

Comment: @SKSingh Your latest code update looks like it should work with the exception of the `return onMessage(ch, method, properties, body)` line.  The `onMessage()` function gets called when `basic_consume()` function completes -- so if you want to print the body put a `print()` statement in the onMessage function.   Take a look at this question about callbacks  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081243/how-to-use-a-callback-function-in-python.